# Sprite Kit and bitmap fonts

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ios7, kobold2d

I am currently using Cocos2D, but also reading new iOS Sprite Kit docs. However, I'm not able to find how to use bitmap fonts. Is there any trick to use my `.fnt` files?

Comment: glyph designer update with bitmap font class for SK is in development. SK also has a private SKBitmapFont class so this may be coming in a future version of SK.

Comment: Unless something happens soon... no change yet. No bitmap fonts in 2015. Also no 3x atlas support yet. Did Apple just neglect SpriteKit, or abandon it completely?

Answer (score 0):

Sprite Kit doesn't officially support bitmap fonts yet, so you will either have to implement your own or use one of the two options below:

1) BMGlyph - http://www.bmglyph.com/tutorials-spritekit-bitmap-font/

2) Glyph Designer - https://71squared.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200037472-Using-Glyph-Designer-1-8-with-Sprite-Kit

Both are great and will get the job done. I personally prefer BMGlyph because you get access to the code and the code is the same for OS X and iOS.