# Gradient/Outline Font SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I am wondering how people currently implement Gradient/Outlined fonts in SpriteKit or if not is there any way to do this.

I seen this question:

[What would be the best approach for outlining or dropshadowing a font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211827/what-would-be-the-best-approach-for-outlining-or-dropshadowing-a-font)

But there were no real answers for outlining.

I noticed for UILabel there was:

https://github.com/vigorouscoding/KSLabel

Which seemed to be exactly what I want but I'm not sure on how to move that sort of thing over to a SKLabelNode.

Thanks in advance to your help.

EDIT: I'm thinking this might be possible with a texture atlas like in CCLabelAtlas anyone know if SpriteKit supports these (I'm guessing not).

Comment: for that you can use bitmap fonts created by: http://71squared.com/en/glyphdesigner

Comment: @LearnCocos2d Hmmm so with that tool I could load a font at an outline / gradient then save this down to a bitmap font ?

Comment: You can design a bitmap font with outlines, shadows, gradients within the tool, based on a truetype font of your choice.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Sounds good you want to add this as an answer ?