# Swift Outlined SKLabelNodes

Tags: swift, text, sprite-kit

I am making a game with `SpriteKit's` framework. How would I make an outlined text with `SKLabelNodes`? There doesn't seem to be a built in function of doing this. If there is no way to do it within `SpriteKit`, what other ways could I approach this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211827/what-would-be-the-best-approach-for-outlining-or-dropshadowing-a-font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I didn't know how to implement UILabels or NSAttributedLabelNodes onto a SpriteKit GameScene, so I just put 4 SKLabels in black behind the original SKLabel (same font size). I then adjusted the 4 black SKLabels, one going a little to the left (relative to the original label), a little to the right, a little up, a little down. This gave an outlining illusion. Pretty bootleg solution but it works. Hopefully SpriteKit implements a better built in option!

Hope this helps someone!