# SKLabelNode + NSMutableAttributedString = no shadow

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring, sklabelnode

```
    let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraph.alignment = NSTextAlignment.right
    paragraph.tailIndent = -3
    let shadow = NSShadow()
    shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 5
    shadow.shadowColor = UIColor.gray
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: -2)
    let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "MY LABEL", attributes:
   [NSShadowAttributeName : shadow,
    NSStrokeColorAttributeName : UIColor.black,
    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : -3,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white,
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "MyFont", size: 24) as Any,
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraph])

    let node = SKLabelNode()
    addChild(node)
    node.attributedText = attributedString
```

It works but there is NO shadow. I can use the same `NSMutableAttributedString` on well-known `ASAttributedLabel` and it works nice and there IS a shadow, but i want to use `SKLabelNode` to achieve better performance on `IOS11`. `ASAttributedLabel` may lag on dynamic scenes :(

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm in the same situation

Comment: it was a long time ago, but as far as I remember, I did not found any solution. but hey, it was iOS11 back then, maybe there is fresh workaround. sorry can't be more helpful

Comment: @user3582537, [What would be the best approach for outlining or dropshadowing a font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211827/what-would-be-the-best-approach-for-outlining-or-dropshadowing-a-font)