# How to get SKLabelNode score with image Numbers in spritekit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, sprite-kit

i am making a game with sprite kit for iphone.  In the gameScene.m im adding score with image numbers so  i can get the 1 and 2 digit score by the below  2 cases but i want to add 3 digit score in case3,please as me  if u need to know more about this ask me before downgrading thanks.

```
 //int _gamescore;
_gameScore = 0;
_finalScore = [SKSpriteNode node];
 NSString *digit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",_gameScore];
[self setScore:(int)digit.length];

-(void)setScore:(int)numberofDigitsInScore
  {
    NSMutableString *scorestring = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%i", _gameScore];
    [_finalScoreSprite removeAllChildren];
    double val1;
    int sides;
     CGFloat y = self.size.height/2 -10;//position of score on screen

switch (numberofDigitsInScore) {
   case 1:      //  0-9 numbers
       {
           NSString *digit =[scorestring substringFromIndex:0];
           SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[NSString      
           stringWithFormat:@"Number%@",digit]]; // Number(images 0-9 number images)
           sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, y );
           [_finalScore addChild:sprite];
           break;
       }

 case 2:     //   10-99 numbers
       {
        for (int i = 0; i < scorestring.length; i++) {
            sides =(i!=0)? 1 :-1;
            NSString *digit= [scorestring substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
            SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[NSString
             stringWithFormat:@"Number%i",digit.intValue]];

            if (digit.intValue == 1)
            {
                val1 = 5   ;
            } else{
                val1 = 0;
            }
            sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2 + (17 -val1)*sides, y);
            [_finalScore addChild:sprite];
        }

        break;
}
```

Comment: Is all that code to center your score?

Comment: maybe with a proper string-formatter like e.g. this: `@"%03d"`?

Comment: what do u mean center your score? this is the code for image number score format, i just want case 3 to add 3 digits?

Comment: its not working holex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954144/sprite-kit-and-bitmap-fonts

Comment: can u please remove unclear question with mundi's help it's working perfectly and it will be helpful for others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An acute case of spaghetti code. Try to simplify. Eliminate cryptic variable names such as `val1` or `sides`. You should not write the same code twice and you should generalize enough to work for any number of digits.

```
CGFloat widthOfDigit = .... // figure this out beforehand. Include spacing.
NSString *scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", _score];
CGFloat currentX = (self.size.width - (scoreString.length-1) * widthOfDigit) / 2.0
for (int i=0; i<scoreString.length; i++) {
   NSString *digit = [scoreString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,1)];
   SKSpriteNode *digitSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number%@",digit]];
   digitSprite.position = CGPointMake(currentX,y);
   [_finalScore addSprite:digit];
   currentX += widthOfDigit;
}
```

Comment: The font is proportional (see cryptic variable val1).

Comment: Still, my example shows how to simplify this. You can calculate the size differently and then just add a different delta, or you could space the characters a bit to make them the same width.

Comment: Did you try the other answer?

Comment: aiden i tried  with other one but iam unable to use it properly if anyone helps me with that  will be great

Comment: thanks mundi for helping me i figured it out with ur help its working perfectly now

Comment: Please tick the check mark if it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you generalize the code to avoid having to create multiple cases (one for each score length). Here's one way to do that...

1. Create an SKNode
2. Add the digits to the SKNode and set their x positions using the width of each digit (i.e., sprite.size.width) plus some character spacing
3. Use -(CGRect)calculateAccumulatedFrame to determine the bounding box of the SKNode
4. Center the node using the dimensions of the bounding box

**EDIT:** Here's code to center a string of proportional bitmap characters

```
- (SKSpriteNode *) createScoreNode
{
    SKSpriteNode *score = [SKSpriteNode node];
    SKNode *node = [SKNode new];
    NSString *scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 12122];
    CGFloat posX = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<[scoreString length]; i++) {
        NSString *digit = [scoreString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,1)];
        SKSpriteNode *digitSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number%@",digit]];
        digitSprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
        digitSprite.position = CGPointMake(posX,0);
        [node addChild:digitSprite];
        posX += digitSprite.size.width + kCharacterSpacing;
    }
    CGRect boundingBox = [node calculateAccumulatedFrame];
    CGFloat nodeX = -boundingBox.size.width/2;
    CGFloat nodeY = -boundingBox.size.height/2;

    node.position = CGPointMake(nodeX, nodeY);

    [score addChild:node];
    return score;
}
```

Comment: it will be good if u place some example here or modify my code it will be great

Comment: I see that you already accepted an answer, but I edited my answer anyway so you could compare approaches.

Comment: did not tried this yet but will do soon now im working on sound on/off

Comment: hi today i got funny bug when run this on simulator number with images getting prfectly but when im running on iphone its showing just x boxes and bud (SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "Number1"
2014-10-01 20:25:14.916 Ring[1454:518317] SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "Number1") for all the numbers?

Comment: Two things to check: 1) is the image's name spelled correctly? the simulate is not case sensitive but devices are and 2) you were testing on a non-retina simulator device and your device is retina. In latter case, you will need a retina version of the image called "Number1@2x.png".

Comment: yea its  spelled correctly all the numbers and made retina versions as well tried with retina and non retina on my iphone 5s its given same problem i donno what to do

Comment: i just fixed it :) i change the sizes to 1x-30x42 and @2x-60x82  of all the numbers and deleted the file from the folder and added again then its working fine