# SpriteKit shader crash iOS 9: SKDefaultShading, gl_FragCoord

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit, ios9

Just installed the iOS 9 open beta (version 3) and now I'm having loads of problems with SpriteKit shaders. On iOS 8 the following code worked just fine:

```
_fontShader = [SKShader shaderWithFileNamed:@"TheShader"]; // TODO: iOS9 compatibility issues here
_fontUniform = [SKUniform uniformWithName:@"labelBase" float:0];
[self.fontShader addUniform:self.fontUniform]; // TODO: iOS9 compatibility issues here

_fontEffects = [SKEffectNode node];
self.fontEffects.shader = self.fontShader; // TODO: iOS9 compatibility issues here
self.fontEffects.shouldEnableEffects = YES;
self.fontEffects.shouldCenterFilter = NO;
self.fontEffects.shouldRasterize = YES;
[self addChild:self.fontEffects];
```

Edit: the file "TheShader.fsh" looks like this:

```
float yPos = gl_FragCoord.y - labelBase; // iOS 9 Compatibility issues here
float gradient = 0.35*(yPos / u_sprite_size.y); // ranges from 0 at base to 0.35 at top

vec4 color = SKDefaultShading(); // the current label color (iOS 9 Compatibility issues here)
color = vec4(gradient + color.r, gradient + color.g, gradient + color.b, color.a);
color.rgb *= color.a; // set background to alpha 0

gl_FragColor = color;
```

On iOS 9 the console is spewing out a pile of warnings in this format:

```
2015-07-12 22:43:17.717 ReconInForce[599:110531] Jet: Error Domain=MTLLibraryErrorDomain Code=3 "Compilation failed: 

program_source:8:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gl_FragCoord'
    float yPos = gl_FragCoord.y - labelBase[0];
                 ^
program_source:11:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'SKDefaultShading'
    vec4 color = SKDefaultShading(); // the current label color
             ^
" UserInfo=0x158c084b0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Compilation failed: 

program_source:8:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gl_FragCoord'
    float yPos = gl_FragCoord.y - labelBase[0];
             ^
program_source:11:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'SKDefaultShading'
    vec4 color = SKDefaultShading(); // the current label color
             ^
}
```

Seems like iOS9 is not supporting SKDefaultShading and gl_FragCoord. How do I find the local pixel dimension without using gl_FragCoord?

The console continues to repeat this forever, slowing down the device. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

If I comment out the lines above that say "iOS9 compatibility issues here" then the problem resolves itself, but then I don't have any shaders.

Anyone else having this issue? Much help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is more than likely a bug on their side. I was updating some stuff today and ran into these problems as well.

Comment: Did figure this out? Running into the same issue on Xcode 7.0 and iOS 9.1 public beta 1.

Comment: Not yet, file a bug report if you can. The more reports the faster they might fix it!

Comment: When will Apple pay attention to SpriteKit, my games are all broken in iOS9, im receiving bad reviews, and its not my fault. This is terrible.
Anyone have a radar number yet?

Comment: The SDK documentation doesn't mention anything about SKDefaultShading being deprecated or anything. I filed a bug and gave feedback on the doc page as well, see if they update it, https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShader_Ref/index.html

Comment: I just created a small example that shows a SpriteKit shader that works with either OpenGL or Metal. Have a peek at https://github.com/mdejong/SKShaderBWWindow/

Comment: FWIW, `SKDefaultShading()` seems to work from circa iOS 9.3, and specifically not on iOS 9.2. (When not forcing OpenGL through the Info.plist file)

Comment: And in place of `SKDefaultShading()` I could use `texture2D(u_texture, v_tex_coord);` in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My custom SKShader also stopped working in ios9 on metal devices.

I was able to fix it using v_tex_coord to get the pixel position,   and  custom uniform to send in the sprite size (There seems to be a bug where u_sprite_size isn't being passed in.)

```
[SKUniform uniformWithName:@"u_fixed_size" floatVector2:GLKVector2Make(n.calculateAccumulatedFrame.size.width, n.calculateAccumulatedFrame.size.height)]
```

Comment: Can you please add more information and code, how to substitute / calculate gl_FragCoord based on what you mentioned in your accepted answer. Many Thanks!

Comment: This does not solve the issues for me. SKDefaultShading() seems to be gone.

Comment: BTW I think `u_sprite_size` is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

I came here after seeing the message **use of undeclared identifier 'gl_FragCoord'**
but eventually I could solve my problem by replacing

> gl_FragCoord.xy / u_sprite_size.xy

with

> v_tex_coord

Comment: Ok this helped me with a similar problem. Seemed `gl_FragCoord ` was bad too.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add parameter 'PrefersOpenGL' of type boolean set to 'YES' in info.plist. This will disable Metal

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too with iOS9. `gl_FragCoord` stopped working on real devices, but works in the iOS simulator.

Work around.

Create a node with shader

```
let shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "polka.fsh")
let uniform = SKUniform(name: "u_spriteSize", floatVector2: GLKVector2Make(Float(200), Float(200)))
shader.uniforms.append(uniform)
```

Update the uniform

```
if let uniform = shader.uniformNamed("u_spriteSize") {
    let size = frame.size
    uniform.floatVector2Value = GLKVector2Make(Float(size.width * screenScale), Float(size.height * screenScale))
}
```

Shader

```
vec2 xy = v_tex_coord * u_spriteSize - u_polkaCenter; // new code
//vec2 xy = gl_FragCoord.xy - u_polkaCenter;  // old code that worked before iOS9
```